# Bootstrap col at the end of the page with image

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a html page that has been by bootstrap 4.

I wish to divide a col in two part and each part had a particular background color and in the middle an image. I wish to have  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zQ3D.png)

But I'm able to do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYUO8.png)

My code is:

```html
 

    <div class="col-sm-2" id="s1" style="padding-top: 12rem">
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" style=" min-height: 100%">
                <div class="col-sm-6  no-float" style="background-color: #1e7e34; min-height: 100%">
                    One of three columns
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6  no-float" style="background-color: silver; min-height: 100%">
                    One of three columns
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <img src="Image.png" style="max-width:80%; max-height:80%;" align="center">
</div>
```

The height is the image, but the image change for each page because the final user can insert the image.

Have you an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can add to image, a bootstrap class. It makes image align middle of that column

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div class="col-sm-2" id="s1" style="padding-top: 12rem">
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" style=" min-height: 100%">
                <div class="col-sm-6  no-float" style="background-color: #1e7e34; min-height: 100%">
                    One of three columns
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6  no-float" style="background-color: silver; min-height: 100%">
                    One of three columns
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="Image.png" style="max-width:80%; max-height:80%;" align="center">
</div>
```